# Tempo verbale in una recensione

Tags: verbs, past-tense

Sto scrivendo una recensione per uno spettacolo teatrale, che fu messo in scena 3 settimane fa. Mi è venuto un dubbio su quale tempo verbale usare, passato remoto o passato prossimo?

Ad esempio, si consideri la frase: "Di conseguenza però, la recitazione fu leggermente carente, dato che Elisa ebbe poca esperienza teatrale rispetto ad altri attori." è corretta?

O sarebbe meglio scrivere: "Di conseguenza però, la recitazione è stata leggermente carente, dato che Elisa ha avuto poca esperienza teatrale rispetto ad altri attori."

Comment: Personalmente mi suonano un po' forzate entrambe; io userei l'imperfetto.

Comment: il problema che usando l'imperfetto non è più coeso con il resto del paragrafo, in cui ho usato principalmente passato remoto o passato prossimo.

Comment: Io userei senza dubbio il passato prossimo, ma questo è quasi certamente una conseguenza del mio italiano regionale e non la regola "standard".

Comment: Toglierei *però*, prima di tutto: se stai enunciando una conseguenza, non c'è un'avversativa (a meno che non usi *però* nel desueto significato di *perciò*, ma sarebbe comunque ridondante). Personalmente userei il passato prossimo *la recitazione è stata*, ma *fu* va bene. In entrambi i casi, lo stato di Elisa è prolungato nel tempo: *Elisa aveva poca esperienza*.

Comment: Intendevo che userei ovunque l'imperfetto; mi sembra il tempo più adatto a una recensione.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Sfogliando rapidamente un volume di recensioni teatrali di Vincenzo Cardarelli (_Una poltrona vuota_) vedo che usava qua e là vari tempi verbali – essenzialmente i tre possibili passati più il presente storico – forse con una prevalenza di passati remoti. Per fare un esempio simile al testo dell'OP: “L'interpretazione di questo dramma fu incerta. Più di un artista parve non sentirsi ad agio nei panni del personaggio eroico che doveva raffigurare. ... La signora M.C. Bagni ‘rimediò’ con molta efficacia la parte [che un'altra attrice non aveva potuto interpretare]” (p. 159).

Answer (score 4):

Passato remoto o prossimo nella principale è una scelta stilistica; a parte l'uso regionale, *l'interpretazione fu* colloca in un tempo completamente trascorso, mentre *l'interpretazione è stata* può suggerire al lettore che il recensore ha ancora ben presente quell'interpretazione.

Il tempo verbale riguardante Elisa dev'essere l'imperfetto. Esempio analogo:

> Dato che *avevo* poca esperienza di teatro, la compagnia mi allontanò.

La struttura è identica e **dato che ebbi* è inaccettabile. Nel caso in esame le due parti della frase sono scambiate, ma la scelta del tempo verbale non cambia. Sarebbe diversa in

> *Ebbi* poca esperienza di teatro perché la compagnia mi allontanò presto.

ma potrebbe essere

> *Avevo* poca esperienza di teatro perché la compagnia mi aveva allontanato presto, eppure il noto attore mi chiamò.
>
> Il noto attore mi chiamò sebbene *avessi* poca esperienza di teatro.

---

Eliminerei il *però*: il significato attuale è lo stesso di *ma* e **ma di conseguenza* non funziona: non c'è nulla da avversare.<sup>1</sup> Per la verità, anche il *di conseguenza* non mi pare ben collocato, perché la causa della recitazione carente è esposta dopo, ma *di conseguenza* richiede che la causa sia già nota.

> Elisa aveva poca esperienza di teatro rispetto agli altri attori e di conseguenza la recitazione fu piuttosto carente.

Personalmente cercherei di evitare di dare tutte le colpe alla povera Elisa, come sembra trasparire dalla frase in esame:

> La recitazione fu piuttosto carente, in parte perché si notava la poca esperienza teatrale di Elisa rispetto agli altri attori.

(anche qui imperfetto: l'atto del notare è prolungato nel tempo).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Se *però* fosse inteso nel desueto senso di *perciò*, sarebbe comunque ridondante.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Come consigliato in altre risposte, l'errore non sta nella scelta del passato remoto o del passato prossimo, bensí nel *non* usare l'indicativo imperfetto per riferirsi alle scarse capacità di recitazione di Elisa.

Uno spettacolo messo in scena tre settimane fa richiederebbe l'uso del passato remoto. L'evento, infatti, è concluso e non ha rapporti con il presente. Se un registro formale ed un uso sorvegliato della lingua sono appropriati per l'articolo che stai scrivendo, usa senza dubbio il passato remoto. Nel registro informale (e soprattutto nel Settentrione) è invece comune l'uso del passato prossimo. Ti rimando a [questo articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca](https://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/ancora-sulluso-passato-remoto) per ulteriori approfondimenti.

Ciò che invece va corretto è il tempo verbale usato nella seconda parte della frase. Il fatto che Elisa non fosse un'attrice provetta è, sí, riferito al passato, ma si tratta di una condizione della quale ignoriamo l'inizio e la fine. Questo è il caso ideale per usare l'**indicativo imperfetto**:

> L'imperfetto indicativo è un tempo verbale che indica un'azione avvenuta nel passato e considerata nel suo svolgersi, nella sua durata, senza riferimento al suo inizio, alla sua conclusione o al suo scopo.
>
> — *[La grammatica italiana Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/indicativo-imperfetto_(La-grammatica-italiana)/)*

In definitiva, la tua frase potrebbe essere corretta, ad esempio, cosí:

> La recitazione fu leggermente carente, dato che Elisa aveva poca esperienza teatrale rispetto agli altri attori.

Ho anche cambiato "ad altri" in "agli altri", perché immagino tu voglia comparare l'esperienza di Elisa con quella degli altri attori che recitarono insieme a lei, non a quella di altri attori in generale.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!